# MySql SELECT found row when WHERE doesn't match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a pretty simple table called roles:

[image]

When I ran `SELECT * FROM roles WHERE role_id = "1ojosd041l"`(the WHERE clause clearly didn't match with any row in the table). It somehow returned this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? My guess is that my role_id column is of type int, but I passed a string into the WHERE clause, so the str to int conversion produced something weird (like a 0 or 1).

I'm just looking for an official explanation for this. If anyone knows why this happens please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: investigate carefully: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: On a side note: Don't use double quotes for string literals. In standard SQL these are for column names, and single quotes are required for strings. In MySQL this depends on session settings. Play save by using the offical correct delimiters (single quotes). And as to your question: `WHERE role_id = '1ojosd041l'` shows that it's often a bad idea to compare different types and rely on implicit conversions. If you really must compare expressions of different types, then cast explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is somee MySQL magic happening here. MySQL sees that role_id is numeric. So it converts your string '1ojosd041l' to a number. This string isn't a number obviously, and MySQL should throw an error. But MySQL just takes as many digits as it finds from the left side of your string instead, so it gets number 1. (If your string started with a non-digit, then MySQL would even return a zero.)

Answer (score 2):

Where MySQL expects a number, it will convert a string to a number, and ignore any leading whitespace or trailing garbage.

If you want to avoid this, do something like

```
SELECT * FROM roles WHERE role_id = "1ojosd041l" and concat(role_id) = "1ojosd041l"
```

Just the second condition would be enough but leaving the first condition in allows an index to be used.

Comment: Explicit CAST would be more clear than CONCAT(), I think...

Comment: @Akina agreed.  I'm just used to concat and typing on my phone